# Why pivotal returns only 404 for every application after I installed WildFly?

Tags: spring-mvc, server, wildfly, pivotal-web-services

Every application that I run on pivotal server is now giving me a 404 although before installing WildFly (+executing standalone.bat) I didn't have any problem using the spring applications. Some applications weren't modified and after this update they wont work.

When I start pivotal and go on localhost:8080 it doesn't show home page for this server; it shows nothing, white page. Only when I start back WildFly I see its default home page.

Spring Tool Suite

Version: 3.7.3.RELEASE
Platform: Eclipse Mars.2 (4.5.2)

This is the problem:

[image: This is the problem]